# How to pick out sublists based upon two numbers in two different positions being equal?

Tags: list-manipulation

This is a scaled down code of what I'm working with:

```
assoc1 = <|"T1" -> 1, "T2" -> 2, "T3" -> 3, "Z1" -> 4|>

lis1 = {{{"T1","T2","T1"}, {"Z1","T3","T2"}, {"T1","T1","Z1"}, {"T2","T3","T3"}}}
lis2 = lis1 /. assoc1
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter through `lis1` and make a few different lists which fit the criteria in which numbers in designated spots within sublists of `lis2` have the same value .  For example let's say I wanted to create another list which is made up of pulled sublists from `lis1` in which the numbers in position 1 and position 3 of any sublist given by `lis2` had the same value, this would give us a new list of:

```
newlis1 = {{{"T1","T2","T1"}}}
```

Likewise, let's say I wanted to only pull out sublists in which the first two or last two numbers within a sublist were equal, this would give two new lists respectively:

`newlis2= {{{"T1","T1","Z1"}}}` and `newlis3 = {{{"T2","T3","T3"}}}`

Is there a generic way to do this?  I was thinking maybe using `DeleteCases` but I hadn't gotten anything along those lines to work.

Comment: `newlis1 = List /@ Cases[lis1, {a_, _, a_}, All]` and `{newlis2, newlise3} = 
 List /@ Cases[lis1, {a_, a_, _} | {_, a_, a_}, All]`?

Answer (score 3):

First and third:

```
Cases[lis1, {x_, _, x_}, {2}]
```

> `{{"T1", "T2", "T1"}}`

First two and last two:

```
Cases[lis1, {x_, x_, _}, {2}]
```

> `{{"T1", "T1", "Z1"}}`

```
Cases[lis1, {_, x_, x_}, {2}]
```

> `{{"T2", "T3", "T3"}}`

I used `Cases` out of habit, but your idea with `DeleteCases` has the advantage that it doesn't change the structure (the level of nesting).

```
DeleteCases[lis1, Except[{_, x_, x_}], {2}]
```

> `{{{"T2", "T3", "T3"}}}`

Answer (score 1):

Your example list *lis1* has 3 levels, but only one element at the first level.  If this is always the case, you could use

```
Select[lis1 // First, 
 assoc1[#[[1]]] == assoc1[#[[2]]] || 
   assoc1[#[[2]]] == assoc1[#[[3]]] &]
```

However, if *lis1* could have more than 1 "row", you could use something like

```
Select[#, 
   assoc1[#[[1]]] == assoc1[#[[2]]] || 
     assoc1[#[[2]]] == assoc1[#[[3]]] &] & /@ lis1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
newlis1 = List /@ Cases[lis1, {a_, _, b_} /;assoc1[a] == assoc1[b], All]
```

> ```
>  {{{"T1", "T2", "T1"}}}
> ```

```
{newlis2, newlis3} = List /@ Cases[lis1, {a_, b_, _} | {_, a_, b_} /; 
     assoc1[a] == assoc1[b], All]
```

> ```
>  {{{"T1", "T1", "Z1"}}, {{"T2", "T3", "T3"}}}
> ```

```
pIck = Pick[#, Apply[Equal, (# /. #2)[[All, #3]], {-2}]] &;

pIck[First@lis1, assoc1, {1, 3}]
```

> ```
>  {{"T1", "T2", "T1"}}
> ```

```
pIck[First@lis1, assoc1, ;; 2]
```

> ```
>  {{"T1", "T1", "Z1"}}
> ```

```
pIck[First@lis1, assoc1, 2 ;;]
```

> ```
>  {{"T2", "T3", "T3"}}
> ```